# chrome extension input value into input

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have problems while programing simple value input bot and do next input depending on what page outputs. In some class on page will be 1 It have to input 1 otherwise if it throws at me 0 I have to input 0, wich has to create value and put it into some input on page and click on button with specific id to submit value.

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "bot",
  "description": "bot",
  "version": "1.0",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["bg.js"]
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "http://*/*"
  ]
}
```

bg.js

```
function checkForValidUrl(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if (tab.url.indexOf("cs") > -1) {
        chrome.pageAction.show(tabId);
    }
}

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(checkForValidUrl);

chrome.pageAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {code: "document.getElementById('input').value = '1';"});
});
```

thats all i put together but it doesn't work

Comment: can you put the rest of the code? including the manifest

Comment: try adding [`pageAction` specification](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction) to your manifest.json